# Igraph keep the edge with the highest weight when nodes have a circular connection

Tags: r, igraph

I have a much larger graph like the one in the links below where some nodes have an incoming and an outgoing edge that have different weights. I'm afraid I'm struggling to find a way to identify the edges to be removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(100)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(data.frame(v_1 = c(1,2,1,3, 1, 3), v_2 = c(2,1,3,1, 4, 4)), directed = TRUE)

E(g)$weights <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3)

plot.igraph(g, edge.width=E(g)$weights, edge.curved = 0.3)
```

[Graph that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtdZM.png)

[Graph that I want to get to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zONk.png)

Comment: `delete.edges()` can help here. Another option would to work on the data (making it undirected based on edge weights) before the graph

Comment: Thank you ANG got my thinking differently enough to find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little cheeky answering your own question but big thanks to ANG's comment for getting my brain working.

Been struggling with this for a while but here's a solution that works in my scenario. Hope it helps someone with a similar issue.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(100)

df <- data.frame(v_1 = c(1,2,1,3, 1, 3), v_2 = c(2,1,3,1, 4, 4))
df$weights <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3)

#Order the vertex IDs so that an edge between 1-2 and 2-1 both become 1-2, then collapse them together so they're in 1 column that can be used to identify the duplicate.
df$ordered_verticies <- apply(df[1:2], 1, FUN = function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))

#order by vertice, then negative weight for a decending order
df <- df[order(df$ordered_verticies, -df$weights),]

#removing duplications now gets rid of the the second (and lower weighted) instance of an edge
df <- df[!duplicated(df$ordered_verticies),]

#new graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df[1:2], directed = TRUE)
E(g)$weights <- df[,3]
plot.igraph(g, edge.width=E(g)$weights, edge.curved = 0.3)
```

Comment: There's no better way to learn than finding the answer by yourself! Thanks for sharing :)